# Is it possible to write in cell like POI using POITransformer?

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is what I need to do.

```
1) Accept an xlsx/xls file from client.
2) Backend will receive it in the form of multipart file
3) The file will be processed and if the format of the data is invalid, that same file will be updated and the error message will be written in the side of the input of the client.
4) this modified file will be sent back to the user.
```

But after several attempts, I could not make my code work.

```
def generateErrorReport(ServletResponse response, Map messageCollections, MultipartFile file, String ext){

    FileInputStream fileIn = file.getInputStream()
    Workbook workbook = (ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) ? new HSSFWorkbook(fileIn) : new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn)

    workbook = this.getWorkbook((MultipartFile) file, ext.equalsIgnoreCase("xls"));
    try {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
        Long lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        for(int i=1; i<sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
            if(messageCollections[i]!=null && messageCollections[i]!=[] ) {
                Cell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(lastCellNum + 1)
                cell.setCellValue(messageCollections[i]);
            }
        }

        fileIn.close()

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream((File) file)
        workbook.write(fileOut);

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=error.xlsx")
        response.outputStream << fileOut
        response.outputStream.flush()

        fileOut.close()
    }catch(Exception ex){
        println ex
    }
}
```

Now, I think a found way to do it, that is to use POITransformer. The problem is it is used when you have a template. My idea was to use the file sent by the client as template and then just simply write the error message beside the client's input. However I couldnt find a way to write it because I couldn't find a setCellData or any method same as that.

The question is, is it possible to write to a desired cell data using POITransformer? If yes, how will I do that?

So far this is what i've done. But it still not writing. Could you tell me whats wrong?

```
private void bla(ServletResponse response, Map messageCollections, MultipartFile file, String ext){
        InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = response.outputStream;

        String fileName = "error";
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=${fileName}");
        try {

            PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is, os);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = transformer.getWorkbook()
            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex())
            int lastColNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()

            Cell cellData;
            (0..sheet.getLastRowNum()) {
                if (messageCollections[it]!=null && messageCollections[it]!=[]) {
                    cellData = sheet.getRow(it).getCell(lastColNum+1);
                    cellData.setCellValue(messageCollections[it].toString())
                }
            }

            transformer.write();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          println ex
//            Logger.getLogger(ExcelFileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            closeStream(is);
            closeStream(os);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this answer would be helpful to others.

```
    InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = response.outputStream;

    String fileName = "desiredFilename." + ext

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=${fileName}");
    try {

        PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(is, os);
        org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = transformer.getWorkbook()
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(workbook.getActiveSheetIndex())
        int lastColNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()

        Cell cell;

        cell = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(lastColNum);
        if(cell==null){
            cell = sheet.getRow(0).createCell(lastColNum);
        }
        cell.setCellType(1)
        cell.setCellValue("Message")
        cell.setCellStyle(getStyle(workbook, 2))

        for(int it=1; it<sheet.getLastRowNum(); it++) {
            if (message.get(new Long(it))!=null && message.get(new Long(it))!=[]) {
                cell = sheet.getRow(it).getCell(lastColNum);
                if(cell==null){
                    cell = sheet.getRow(it).createCell(lastColNum);
                }
                cell.setCellType(1)
                cell.setCellValue(message.get(new Long(it)).join(', '))
                cell.setCellStyle(getStyle(workbook, 1))
            }
        }

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(lastColNum);
        transformer.write();
```